# How to handle System.InvalidOperationException?

Tags: data-binding

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred when I want to display database data in listbox through a backgroundworker

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private List<Product> products;

        private void LstProduct_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            products = App.StoreDb.GetProducts();

        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Lstproducts.ItemsSource = products;
        }



}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
private void LstProduct_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //create thread 
  ThreadStart myThreadStart = new ThreadStart(MyThreadRoutine);
  Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadStart);
  myThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
  myThread.Start();
}

//function
private void MyThreadRoutine()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {    
          products = App.StoreDb.GetProducts();
          this.LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          this.Lstproducts.ItemsSource = products;
         });
    }
```